# Spring cacheManager is not singleton?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have some problems with an spring AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.

The main aim is to create a Spring Configuration which can be run on application server or standalone. Subtask to make subcontext from this one which will be used by another application on the same AppServer. 
But have some trouble with cacheManager.

That's my code:
aka AbstractConfig

```
package org.zib.test.a;


import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Arrays;


@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class ConfigA {

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return ContextA.getInstance().getContext();
    }


/**
 * use {@link org.zib.test.b.ContextB}
 */
public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> bean) {
    return ContextB.getInstance().getContext().getBean(bean);
}
/**
 * use {@link ContextB}
 */
public static <T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> bean) {
    return ContextB.getInstance().getContext().getBean(name, bean);
}

    @Bean(name = "cacheManager")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        // configure and return an implementation of Spring's CacheManager SPI
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("default")));
        return cacheManager;
     }

 }
```

aka AbstractContext

```
package org.zib.test.a;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class ContextA {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ContextA instance;

    public static ContextA getInstance() {
        synchronized (ContextA.class) {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ContextA();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ContextA() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(ConfigA.class);
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
        applicationContext.refresh();
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Mode Config (for example, WebLogicConfig)

```
package org.zib.test.b;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.zib.test.a.ConfigA;


@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@Import(ConfigA.class)
public class ConfigB {

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return ContextB.getInstance().getContext();
    }
    /**
     * use {@link ContextB}
     */
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> bean) {
        return ContextB.getInstance().getContext().getBean(bean);
    }
    /**
     * use {@link ContextB}
     */
    public static <T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> bean) {
        return ContextB.getInstance().getContext().getBean(name, bean);
    }
}
```

context:

```
package org.zib.test.b;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.zib.test.a.ContextA;

public class ContextB {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ContextB instance;

    public static ContextB getInstance() {
        synchronized (ContextB.class) {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ContextB();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ContextB() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(ConfigB.class);
        applicationContext.setParent(ContextA.getInstance().getContext());
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
        applicationContext.refresh();
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

And final - module config:

```
package org.zib.test.c;


import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Arrays;


@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class ConfigC {

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return ContextC.getInstance().getContext();
    }
    /**
     * use {@link ContextC}
     */
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> bean) {
        return ContextC.getInstance().getContext().getBean(bean);
    }

    /*DELTE BY SUGGESTION OF Tomasz Nurkiewicz
    @Bean(name = "cacheManager")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("default")));
        return cacheManager;
    }*/
}
```

and its context:

```
package org.zib.test.c;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.zib.test.a.ContextA;
import org.zib.test.b.ContextB;

public class ContextC {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ContextC instance;

    public static ContextC getInstance() {
        synchronized (ContextC.class) {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ContextC();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ContextC() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(ConfigC.class);
        applicationContext.setParent(ContextA.getInstance().getContext());
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
        applicationContext.refresh();
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
package org.zib.test;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.zib.test.a.ConfigA;
import org.zib.test.c.ConfigC;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object cm1 = ConfigC.getBean(CacheManager.class);
        Object cm2 = ConfigA.getBean(CacheManager.class);

        if (cm1 == cm2)
            System.out.println("equals");
        else
            System.out.println("unequal");
    }
}
```

i've already spent a lot of time to solve this problem - will be happy if anyone will help me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly `A` is a parent context with two children: `B` and `C`. You define `cacheManager` twice: in parent `ConfigA` and in one child `ConfigC`. Different application contexts can have the same beans, that's why you get two different instances.

In other words if you ask for `cacheManager` from `ConfigC`, it returns the one defined in that context. But if you ask for it from `ConfigB` or `ConfigA`, it'll return the one from `ConfigA` (other instance).

They are still singletons, but within the scope of a single application context. BTW can you describe what you want to achieve with this pretty complex architecture?

Comment: the same problem after deletion second cacheManager declaration

Comment: About the aim: i have a modular solution. This solution can be executed on Application Server and standalone (so there are different way to achieve some object, for example DataSource and etc) but common part of this i include in ConfigA. After that, each module has an own configuration with specific beans. I agree that it's pretty complex, but as for me - very logically